# How can i verify contract in bscscan if i was already deployed using remix.ethereum.org?

Tags: token, ethereum, blockchain, ether

Suppose I have created a token using `remix.ethereum.org`, the token has already been deployed and can now be sold on platforms such as pancakeswap for example, however, I still need to verify the contract on the token's profile on bscscan , after researching I noticed that it is possible to verify it when the token is created using remix.ethereum.org, but I didn't do it, and the token was already created.

How can i do this verification?

I need do commit all the codes in bscscan, but will i have to do individually? I mean, which files i commit?